# Path of the binary tree which has the highest number of bends

Tags: algorithms, binary-trees

It is an interview question:

> Given a binary tree print the path of the tree which has
>   the highest number of bends.

I could come up with a solution which will keep track the left or right child being called but interviewer was not satisfied with that solution. Has anyone better solution for this problem?

Comment: It's hard to answer this question without a better description of your solution.

Comment: If you are allowed to annotate your binary tree, you can add a pointer to each inner node which points at the deeper child. This will result in an $O(n)$ solution.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Wouldn't a straightforward depth-first traversal work fine in $O(n)$ time? I don't see any need to annotate the tree.

Comment: @DerekElkins You need to return the path, not just the depth.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus So you build a linked list as you return back up the tree. Prepending to a linked list is a constant-time operation, so this doesn't affect the asymptotics.

Comment: @DerekElkins That's very similar to my solution, only it will be a mess to release all the memory.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I imagine we're  thinking of the same algorithm, yes. Deallocating isn't an issue in a GCed language. For non-GCed languages you could count the nodes with an $O(n)$ pass and then allocate one array for all the (potential) linked list nodes you might need, and then deallocate them all at once in the end. Even doing the most obvious thing of allocating and deallocating list nodes one at a time wouldn't impact the asymptotics.